# Device Theme Detection In windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8

How  do get the current device theme in wp8 , it seems  like

`Visibility darkBackgroundVisibility =                  (Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"];`

doesnot return the correct value  if the device theme is changed  when your app is the background, is there a workaround to know the current  theme on the device

Answer (score 1):

There is a property for this

```
Visibility v = (Visibility)Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"]; 

if (v == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
{
    // Is light theme
}
else
{
    // Is dark theme
}
```

Comment: this doesnt return the correct value when u change the device them  when u have the app in background, it returns the old value

Answer (score 0):

The app goes in background and when its picked up again, its uses the previous state variables it collected at the time of its launch (note: launch is called once and after that application activated, deactivated events are called). unfortunately, It hence could not detected. you would have to relaunch the app for fresh state variables.